# How to set all values for a column to a max value on a certain WHERE?

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, correlated-subquery

If I have:

```
 2 baskets of oranges with 7 and 10 each

 3 baskets of peaches with 12 and 15 each
```

then I want to set:

```
for every orange basket value of maxfruit to 10 and 

for every peach basket value of maxfruit to 15
```

I tried

```
 update baskets set maxfruit = (select max(fruitCount) from baskets b where b.fruit = fruit)
```

but it just sets everything to 15...

Comment: try if this works: update baskets set maxfruit = (select max(fruitCount) from baskets b where b.fruit = fruit) where basket.fruit='fruit'

Comment: the whole point is to not use a specific name :(

Comment: then you'll have to set its maxfruit value to max upon inserting data.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, when you are referencing a column by its name, the table instance that you end up with is the innermost one, unless you use a table prefix.

So `fruit` refers to the innermost instance, `b`. This means that `b.fruit` and `fruit` are always the same value.

To refer to the outer table instance, you must use the name of the outer table:

```
update baskets
set maxfruit = (select max(fruitCount)
                from baskets b
                where b.fruit = baskets.fruit);
                                ^^^^^^^^
```

(And instead of `b.fruit`, you could write just `fruit`, but that could be unclear.)

Answer (score -1):

your update is just pulling the max from the whole table you can use a sub query to pull out the max for each fruit

```
UPDATE b 
SET b.maxfruit = b2.fruitCount 
FROM baskets b 
INNER JOIN (SELECT fruit, MAX(fruitCount) AS fruitCount
            FROM baskets
            GROUP BY fruit) b2 ON b.fruit = b2.fruit
```

Comment: I am not sure this works in SQLite. It just returns me an error at '.'

Comment: That is T-SQL you should be able to do similar in SQLlite